# AnyLogic: How do I create shelves from which a person can pick totes from and to?

Tags: anylogic

I need to pick totes from and to a shelve similar to a rackstorage. The problem is that racks only allow pallets and I need to simulate a person picking totes from several shelves of 3 levels height and 3 columns. Any Feedback?

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply substitute :

- pallets for totes (just make your pallet dimensions smaller)
- rack storage for your tote storage
- transporters for humans

Then you can create your model using the same objects available in the Material Handling Library, just change the dimensions to match your actual objects